# Add absolute paths to app created by "Create React App"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have created an app by [Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) and to be more specific I'm also using typescript.

I can't figerout how to set absolute paths to access to my components, pages, etc..

In a different scenario I would update my tscongig with something like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@components/*": ["src/components/*"]
      }
    }
  }
```

but I have no idea how to implement this as I'm using `react-scripts`
any idea?

Answer (score 14):

Create a tsconfig.json file and add the code below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Then you can import your components as

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the same approach if create a *jsconfig.json* file in your solution, which supports the same baseUrl and rootPath properties as tsconfig.

Alternative is adding an *.env* file in your solution with the following line:

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

Also, apart from the env file add this to your jsconfig.json

```
{
  "rootDir": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This should resolve both the compiler being able to find your absolute imports, and linter handling them properly.

Comment: I have set multiples file for the compilation, .env and .env.production but I'm looking for something to be able to call `@components/*` and not `/src/common/components/*`

Comment: I updated the comment. It should allow you to import things like `import { Something } from 'components'`. If a path is not resolved from node_modules it will try to resolve it from the src folder. +

Answer (score 1):

See [Building Your App / Importing a Component / Absolute Imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) in the Create React App docs.

> You can configure your application to support importing modules using absolute paths. This can be done by configuring a `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project. If you're using TypeScript in your project, you will already have a `tsconfig.json` file.
>
> Below is an example `jsconfig.json` file for a JavaScript project. You can create the file if it doesn't already exist:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "baseUrl": "src"
>    },
>   "include": ["src"]
> }
> ```
>
> If you're using TypeScript, you can configure the `baseUrl` setting inside the `compilerOptions` of your project's `tsconfig.json` file.
>
> Now that you've configured your project to support absolute imports, if you want to import a module located at `src/components/Button.js`, you can import the module like so:
>
> ```
> import Button from 'components/Button';
> ```